# PostGIS Street Intersection Autocomplete with full text search

Tags: postgis, intersection

What I'm attempting to do is create a custom autocomplete for addresses, road intersections, POI's, etc.

For now we are going to using Mapbox GL (we'll be creating a custom map at a later phase), which currently only supports addresses and POI's. Additionally, we will be adding and extracting data from the shape files below.

http://rlisdiscovery.oregonmetro.gov/?action=viewDetail&layerID=556#

http://www.civicapps.org/datasets/street-centerlines

What I've been struggling with is creating a ST_Intersection self join query for the intersecting streets portion of the autocomplete.

The goals include:

1) Street intersection using " / " instead of the customary "&".

2) Partial matching with rank (i.e. "7th Ave & Stark St" would include both SE "7th Ave / SE Stark St" and "SW 7th Ave / SW Stark St").

3) Use of the custom tables and have either TIGER or OSM tables as a fall back for addresses or intersecting streets that outside the area.

I already have the tables created with the appropriate SRID's for each. If needed, I can explode the lines for point data and/or create a new topology edge table, if needed.

Comment: From your question it doesn't become completely clear what you are trying to do or what your problem is. Are you working with postgis-topology? Maybe you can add a more verbose example or add an SQL query that you already worked on?